# Developing a messenger

Tags: java, server, widget, chat, messenger

So I’m developing a chat messenger app like WhatsApp but I’m trying to decide the best way to get the messages between phones. A lecturer of mine mentioned using a router but I couldn’t understand how that would work. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like the best way would to build a server to handle receiving, storing and sending the messages between users. When a user (user1) wants to send a message to another user (user2), they post the message to your server, your server stores the message in some form of database and user2 will receive whatever messages are stored in the db for them. There is an infinite number of ways you could actually architect this.

Edit - not sure if this is actually what you where looking for. let me know if you want me to elaborate.

Comment: thank you ! That’s what I was more thinking of, what do you recommend as the best way to host a server ? The LAMP stack ? The only issue I have with this is php, don’t know much about that

Comment: Depends on what language you prefer. Each language/framework has its pros and cons but If its just for a class I would just go with whatever language your most comfortable with. If you don't like PHP, you could replace it with a django http server and write in python, or you can use NodeJs and write in JS.

Comment: If it were me Id just write a quick node server. Takes about 5 minutes to set up a quick server and its a very light weight straight forward framework. Plus, if Im imagining you project correctly all your going to need is a endpoint to post messages and an endpoint to receive messages (although for the receiving part I would probably use a web socket of some form as to be able to push messages), in node you could write that in like 30 - 40 lines tops.

Comment: that’s brill info, thanks a lot !